# Struggling sending mail using xampp and gmail

Tags: php, email, gmail, xampp, sendmail.exe

I'm trying to send e-mails from my localhost, using my gmail account, I've looked into many ways of solving this, changed my php.ini and sendmail.ini files with no luck, here's part of the files.
Php.ini

```
For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/smtp
SMTP = smtp.gmail.com
; http://php.net/smtp-port
smtp_port = 587

[mail function]


; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/sendmail-from
sendmail_from = andrefpcostaa@gmail.com

; For Unix only.  You may supply arguments as well (default: "sendmail -t -i").
; http://php.net/sendmail-path
sendmail_path = "\"C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t"`
```

and sendmail.ini

```
[sendmail]

; you must change mail.mydomain.com to your smtp server,
; or to IIS's "pickup" directory.  (generally C:\Inetpub\mailroot\Pickup)
; emails delivered via IIS's pickup directory cause sendmail to
; run quicker, but you won't get error messages back to the calling
; application.

smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com

; smtp port (normally 25)

smtp_port=25

; the default domain for this server will be read from the registry
; this will be appended to email addresses when one isn't provided
; if you want to override the value in the registry, uncomment and modify

;default_domain=local

; log smtp errors to error.log (defaults to same directory as sendmail.exe)
; uncomment to enable logging

;error_logfile=error.log

; create debug log as debug.log (defaults to same directory as sendmail.exe)
; uncomment to enable debugging

;debug_logfile=debug.log

; if your smtp server requires authentication, modify the following two lines

auth_username=*************@gmail.com
auth_password=******

; if your smtp server uses pop3 before smtp authentication, modify the 
; following three lines

;pop3_server=
;pop3_username=
;pop3_password=

; to force the sender to always be the following email address, uncomment and
; populate with a valid email address.  this will only affect the "MAIL FROM"
; command, it won't modify the "From: " header of the message content

;force_sender=me@localhost

; sendmail will use your hostname and your default_domain in the ehlo/helo
; smtp greeting.  you can manually set the ehlo/helo name if required

;hostname=localhost`
```

What is wrong? I can't figure it out.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The port is wrong in sendmail.ini for starters - there may be other issues however there is a very good guide to this exact situation here: http://digiex.net/guides-reviews/guides-tutorials/application-guides/544-configuring-php-under-windows-use-gmail-external-smtp-server-ssl.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but no luck. Got this error: Must issue a STARTTLS command first. bu13sm57250448wib.6<EOL>

Answer (score 0):

This will work, fast and easy !

In php.ini, enable this line,

```
sendmail_path = "\"C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t"
```

In sendmail.ini,

```
smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port=465
smtp_ssl=ssl
auth_username=c4engine@gmail.com
auth_password=*******
force_sender=c4engine@gmail.com
```

Restart apache,

```
<?php
$to = "receivername@gmail.com";
$subject = "Test mail";
$message = "Hello! This is a simple email message.";
mail($to,$subject,$message);
echo "Mail Sent.";
?>
```

But please keep in mind, don't enable any other option in [mail function] block of php.ini. Those are to be enabled only if you are using Mercury Mail Server - and there are many steps involved in configuring mercury-mail-server. You better off with sendmail for testing php scripts !